# How can I make a silent install of Firefox in the user windows 7 profile?

Tags: firefox, silent-install

How can I silent install Firefox on the user windows 7 profile without prompting for elevation?

I have tried (whitout success)

```
Firefox setup.exe /ms
Firefox setup.exe -ms -ma
Firefox setup.exe /INI=%temp%\config.ini
```

At all cases above, windows ask for elevation. If user cancel, installation is stoped.

Comment: Did you try renaming the .exe to something without "setup" in it? UAC detects executables with setup in the name as something that will probably require elevation.

Comment: How are you pushing this installation?

Answer (score 1):

Well, isn't that actually what UAC is for? Prevent software to do something, if the user doesn't want it to do.

> What is User Account Control?
>
> User Account Control (UAC) is a security component that enables users
>   to perform common tasks as non-administrators (called standard users
>   in Windows Vista), and as administrators without having to switch
>   users, log off, or use Run As. User accounts that are members of the
>   local Administrators group run most applications as a standard user.
>   By separating user and administrator functions, UAC helps users move
>   toward using standard user rights by default.
>
> When an administrator logs on to a computer that is running Windows 7
>   or Windows Vista, the user is assigned two separate access tokens.
>   Access tokens, which contain a user's group membership and
>   authorization and access control data, are used by the Windows
>   operating system to control what resources and tasks the user can
>   access. The access control model in earlier Windows operating systems
>   did not include any failsafe checks to ensure that users truly wanted
>   to perform a task that required their administrative access token. **As
>   a result, malicious software could install on users' computers without
>   notifying the users. (This is sometimes referred to as a "silent"
>   installation.)**

So I see two solutions for your problem, depending on the number of computers you need to load with software:

1. Tell your people, that there will be a software installation and that they should accept it.
2. If there are too many people/PCs to control, then install some kind of software deployment.

Comment: What I want is to distribute Firefox for users, but I want Firefox to keep updating itself, which is possible only on a user install, not a system install.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Firefox portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable) , it does not need elevated privilages to run.